# Why `scrollIntoView` does not work in Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a component on the page with attribute id like this:

```html
<app-order id="section_14"></app-order>
```

I subscribe to route changes like this:

```js
 ngOnInit() {
     this.route.fragment.pipe(share()).subscribe((fragment) => {
         this.fragment = fragment;
     });
 };
```

Then I try to move user to active fragment (block):

```js
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document){}
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.document.getElementById(this.fragment).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
 }
```

So, `this.fragment` is not empty and `this.document.getElementById(this.fragment)` returns a `DOM` element `<app-order id="section_14"></app-order>`.

Comment: If wrap it in `setTimeout(() => {}, 2000)` it works, why?

Comment: I frogot to says it is two different components

Comment: scrollIntoView works for me but in my case, I should remove { behavior: "smooth" } to work. –

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with the angular lifecycle and change detection.

Try running manual change detection after you set scrollIntoView.

The other thing I think is perhaps the template is not yet rendered when the scrollIntoView is called, in which case a setTimeout with a time of 0 should allow that to succeed (unless there is some sort of async operation that takes a bit to complete)